# Convert HEX color string to Color?

Tags: android

I have a color into the follow format `0xAABBCC` as `String`.
I need to convert it into `Color`, but seems like there is not such method, and all available is returning `Integer` results, which seems incompatible with `Color` object;

- How to create instance of `Color` class from given `HEX` string in the format described above ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use `Color.parseColor("#AABBCC");`

Comment: parseColor is returning integer. Color c = Color.parseColor( "XXX" ); trowing that Color and int is incompatible.

Comment: @BertiKelvin you can use it like  int x= Color.parseColor("#AABBCC");
       tv.setBackgroundColor(x); you set the color to textview

Comment: There is not need to have a instance of the Color class. I think the only reasone for have  a public constructor is for the reflection. In fact setTextColor takes as parameter an int

Comment: seems like I will have no other choice than using it as Int.
Thank You very much. I've got the point.

Answer (score -1):

new Color(Integer.parseInt("AABBCC", 16));

Comment: The constructor Color(int) is undefined. :|

Comment: Can't help you with that, don't have Android here. Take a look into the Android Docs to find a suitable constructor/factory.

Comment: I've tried, but it is going in a dead end with the documentation.

Comment: @BertiKelvin : you can parse Current string to int as `int color =Integer.parseInt("0xAABBCC", 16)` not pass color to `setColor` method where u want to set it

Comment: Did you, by chance, create a class named Color *of your own* or import maybe a different Color class from somewhere else (I accidentially refactored a class to be named Object once, *that* was fun)? I don't think Android will be that different in basic things.

Comment: android.graphics.Color col = new Color( xxxx );
this is what i am trying :|